# Adding a calculated field in LINQ select results?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ query (using with EF)

Basically I want to add a column in Select results based on value of another column.

I have `PaymentDate` column in DB table but not `Paid` column. If there is null in `PaymentDate` column it also shows payment is false and if it has some date in it means paid is true.

Here is my query, please guide me how to do that.

```
 var selectedResults=
    from InvoiceSet in Invoices
    join BookedAreasSet in BookedAreas 
    on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID
    join AreaSet in Areas on BookedAreasSet.AreaID equals AreaSet.AreaID
    select new     {InvoiceSet.InvoiceNumber,InvoiceSet.Amount,InvoiceSet.TotalDiscount,InvoiceSet.GST,       InvoiceSet.PaymentDate,InvoiceSet.ShoppingCentreID,BookedAreasSet.BookedAreaID,
AreaSet.Name,Here I want to add calculated value column based on InvoiceSet.PaymentDate value}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do something like this

```
var selectedResults=
    from InvoiceSet in Invoices
    join BookedAreasSet in BookedAreas 
    on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreasSet.InvoiceID
    join AreaSet in Areas on BookedAreasSet.AreaID equals AreaSet.AreaID
    select new { InvoiceSet.InvoiceNumber,InvoiceSet.Amount,InvoiceSet.TotalDiscount,InvoiceSet.GST,       
        InvoiceSet.PaymentDate,InvoiceSet.ShoppingCentreID,BookedAreasSet.BookedAreaID,
        AreaSet.Name,Paid = (InvoiceSet.PaymentDate == null) }
```